# Setting name of variable in a class with a function?

Tags: python, oop

I have a class and I want to do something like the following:

```
class my_class:

    def my_func(self, var_name):

        self.var_name = 5


a = my_class()
a.my_func('yes')
print(a.yes)
```

I am not sure how to set the class variable name using the function however

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> class my_class(object):
...   def my_func(self,var_name):
...     setattr(self,var_name,5)
...
>>> a = my_class()
>>> a.my_func('yes')
>>> a.yes
5
```